# How can I set the input value of a form in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, opera

Suppose that I have defined a form (`my_form`) that has an input named `myInput`.  I would like to set the value of `myInput` to be `my_string`.

```
$('#my_form textarea[name=myInput]').value = my_string;
```

I've tried the above line, and this works for most browsers, but not for Opera/Safari.  I know it doesn't work for Opera/Safari because the line

```
console.log($('#my_form textarea[name=myInput]').value + " was the string");
```

logs `undefined was the string` to the screen instead of the actual value of my_string (which is not undefined).

How can I achieve this for these browsers?

Comment: It looks like you're using jQuery. Try `.val()` instead of `.value`.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn1").click(function () {
        $("#test1").text("Hello world!");
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function () {
        $("#test2").html("<b>Hello world!</b>");
    });
    $("#btn3").click(function () {
        $("#test3").val("Dolly Duck");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p id="test1">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="test2">This is another paragraph.</p>

<p>Input field: <input type="text" id="test3" value="Mickey Mouse"></p>

<button id="btn1">Set Text</button>
<button id="btn2">Set HTML</button>
<button id="btn3">Set Value</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use *.val()* instead of `.value`. And quotes for a string.

So the final code will be:

```
$("#my_form textarea[name=myInput]").val("my_string_with_quotes_before_and_after");
```

or with variable

```
var string="some text";
$("#my_form textarea[name=myInput]").val(string);
```